Help with combining sensor codes
I'm trying to combine 4 sensors' codes into one to display on the serial monitor: MAX30205, MAX30100, AHT20, and ENS160. I'm using the Adafruit ESP32 Feather V2 board. Here are the libraries that I've used:
https://github.com/gabriel-milan/Arduino-MAX30100
https://github.com/Protocentral/Protocentral_MAX30205
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_AHT20
https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_ENS160
My code compiled and uploaded successfully, but it seems that only the AHT20 and ENS160 display correct data. When I put my finger on the MAX30100 and MAX30205, the sensor data stays at 0 (0 degrees Celsius, 0 bmp, 0% spo2). I need help to see if there's anything I've missed in combining the code. I've tested all the sensors individually and they work fine. This is my code:
#include <DFRobot_ENS160.h>
#include "Protocentral_MAX30205.h"
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
#include <Wire.h>

// Sensor objects
DFRobot_AHT20 aht20;
DFRobot_ENS160_I2C ENS160(&Wire, 0x53);
MAX30205 tempSensor;
PulseOximeter pox;

#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS 1000
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;

// Callback for beat detection
void onBeatDetected() {
  Serial.println("Beat!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();

  // Initialize AHT20 sensor
  uint8_t status;
  while ((status = aht20.begin()) != 0) {
    Serial.print("AHT20 sensor initialization failed. Error status: ");
    Serial.println(status);
    delay(1000);
  }

  // Initialize ENS160 sensor
  while (NO_ERR != ENS160.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Communication with ENS160 device failed, please check connection");
    delay(3000);
  }
  ENS160.setPWRMode(ENS160_STANDARD_MODE);
  ENS160.setTempAndHum(25.0, 50.0);

  // Initialize MAX30205 sensor
  while (!tempSensor.scanAvailableSensors()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find the MAX30205 temperature sensor, please connect the sensor.");
    delay(30000);
  }
  tempSensor.begin();

  // Initialize MAX30100 sensor
  Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter...");
  if (!pox.begin()) {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    for (;;);
  } else {
    Serial.println("SUCCESS");
  }
  pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
}

void loop() {
  // Collect data from AHT20
  if (aht20.startMeasurementReady(true)) {
    float temperature = aht20.getTemperature_C();
    float humidity = aht20.getHumidity_RH();
    Serial.print("AHT2x - Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(temperature);
    Serial.println(" 'C");
    Serial.print("AHT2x - Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(humidity);
    Serial.println(" %RH");
  }

  // Collect data from ENS160
  uint8_t Status = ENS160.getENS160Status();
  uint8_t AQI = ENS160.getAQI();
  uint16_t TVOC = ENS160.getTVOC();
  uint16_t ECO2 = ENS160.getECO2();
  Serial.print("ENS160 - Air quality index: ");
  Serial.println(AQI);
  Serial.print("ENS160 - Concentration of total volatile organic compounds: ");
  Serial.print(TVOC);
  Serial.println(" ppb");
  Serial.print("ENS160 - Carbon dioxide equivalent concentration: ");
  Serial.print(ECO2);
  Serial.println(" ppm");

  // Collect data from MAX30205
  float bodyTemp = tempSensor.getTemperature();
  Serial.print("MAX30205 - Body temperature: ");
  Serial.print(bodyTemp, 2);
  Serial.println(" 'C");

  // Collect data from MAX30100
  pox.update();
  if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
    float heartRate = pox.getHeartRate();
    float SpO2 = pox.getSpO2();
    Serial.print("MAX30100 - Heart rate: ");
    Serial.print(heartRate);
    Serial.println(" BPM");
    Serial.print("MAX30100 - SPO2: ");
    Serial.print(SpO2);
    Serial.println(" %");
    tsLastReport = millis();
  }

  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}```


verify that each sensor is operational ... use separate simple sketch for each sensor ... print values to serial monitor

When you compiled the sketch, you should have seen a report on memory usage. Could you please copy and paste it into your question?

@jsotola all the sensors are functional. I've tested them individually with the example sketches in the libraries I mentioned and they all work well

Delete the delay(1000), move the rest of the code in the loop() with the exception of pox.update() into the if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS)  block.

Definitely try the suggestion from @hcheung to eliminate the delay() and ensure pox.update() is called at loop speed. If that fails create 2 copies of the code, one with all the MAX30205 code removed and the other with all the MAX30100 code removed. Remove also the associated #include statements. Then test both copies. This will help show if there is mutual interference between the two problem sensors. Also update your question with the console output during setup() and one run of the loop().
